# External Merge Sort in C#: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: c#, external, mergesort, disk

So I am trying to implement external Merge Sort in C# but I receive an error, which says: ***Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.***
When I call MergeSort method, I use these parameters:

```
MergeSort(fileName, 0, elementCount - 1)
```

I tried to change from 0 to 1 and from (elementCount -1) to elementCount, but it did not work.
**MergeSort and Merge methods:**

Full error:

> !Unhandled Exception: System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
>      at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
>      at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
>      at Merge_Sort.BinaryOperations.getElement(Int32 index) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\BinaryOperations.cs:line 22
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.Merge(String fileName, Int32 left, Int32 mid, Int32 right) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 70
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.MergeSort(String fileName, Int32 left, Int32 right) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 35
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.MergeSort(String fileName, Int32 left, Int32 right) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 31
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.MergeSort(String fileName, Int32 left, Int32 right) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 33
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.MergeSort(String fileName, Int32 left, Int32 right) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 31
>      at Merge_Sort.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Laptop\source\repos\Merge_Sort\Merge_Sort\Program.cs:line 16

```
static public int MergeSort(string fileName, int left, int right)
        {
            int opCounter = 0;
            opCounter++;
            if(left < right)
            {
                opCounter++;
                int mid = (left + right) / 2;
                opCounter++;
                opCounter += MergeSort(fileName, left, mid);
                opCounter++;
                opCounter += MergeSort(fileName, mid + 1, right);
                opCounter++;
                opCounter += Merge(fileName, left, mid, right);
                opCounter++;
            }
               return opCounter;
        }

        private static int Merge(string fileName, int left, int mid, int right)
        {
            int opCounter = 0;
            number++;
            BinaryOperations mainOp = new BinaryOperations(fileName);
            int num = (int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
            string temp = "b" + num.ToString() + "" + number.ToString() + ".bin";
            string tempFile = "E:/Merge_Sort/Merge_Sort/bin/Debug/temp/" + temp;
            BinaryOperations tempOp = new BinaryOperations(tempFile);

            int size = right - left;
            tempOp.newFile(size);

            int i = 0;
            int j = left;

            for(j = left; j <=mid; j++)
            {
                opCounter++;
                tempOp.setElement(i++, mainOp.getElement(j));
                opCounter += 6;
            }
            i = 0;
            int k = left;
            opCounter += 2;
            while (k < j && j <= right)
            {
                opCounter++;
                opCounter += 12;
                if ((tempOp.getElement(i)) <= (mainOp.getElement(j)))
                {
                    mainOp.setElement(k++, tempOp.getElement(i++));
                    opCounter += 11;
                }
                else
                {
                    mainOp.setElement(k++, mainOp.getElement(j++));
                    opCounter += 11;
                }
            }
            while( k < j)
            {
                opCounter++;
                mainOp.setElement(k++, tempOp.getElement(i++));
                opCounter += 11;
            }

            return opCounter;
        }
```

**BinaryOperations class:**

```
class BinaryOperations
    {
        string fileName;
        public BinaryOperations(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }
        public int getElement(int index)
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(index * 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            int value = reader.ReadInt32();
            reader.Close();
            return value;
        }

        public void setElement(int index, int value)
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
            writer.Seek(index * 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            writer.Write(value);
            writer.Close();
        }
        public void newFile(int size)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                fs.SetLength(size);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is elementCount? the number of bytes in the file? Also the line "reader.BaseStream.Seek(index * 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);" ... why is there a 4 in there - this method is positioning based on bytes and its likely reading past the end of the file.

Comment: @dodgy_coder elementCount is number of integers in my file, for example, my file: " 4 5 6" so the elementCount is 3. index * 4 is because integer takes 4 bytes, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: is it a binary file, or a text file that you can view in Notepad? If its binary then 4 bytes per integer sounds right, but that won't work if its a text file...

Comment: @dodgy_coder yes, it is a binary file, I am using BinaryWriter to fill it with random integers